# WordPress Plugins won't save

Tags: widgets

I have a WordPress website I just took over for a client so I don't have the ability to talk with the previous webmaster / the developer.

The site is using a slightly modified version of the Subway by YOOtheme. To update the plugin location, there is a part of Subway that has "Widget Options". I cannot change the look and feel or what page the widget shows up on because I can't get anything to save. It ether looks like it saved but doesn't or you get the "loading circle" next to the save button that just keeps going.

**Things to note:**

- WordPress and plugins are up to date
- The plugins were updatable right before we transferred to the new server
- The new server has a max_input_vars=2000
- There are a lot of plugins(51 active 10 un-active) being used from the previous developer.
- I tried deactivating all of the plugins to see if it would then save.

I don't know what my next step should be to get this working.

Thanks for the help!!
Katie

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that the theme is outdated and no longer compatible with some core WP functions, the theme was released in 2012 so it's pretty old.